# getElementById() interrupting for-loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementbyid

This part of my code which is creating a lot of columns:

```
for(var i = 0; i<count; i++){
                var Column = data[i].Column;
                var Team = data[i].Team;
                 if(PlannedSprint != data[i].PlannedSprint){

                    $("#sprint_"+Column).append(data[i].PlannedSprint);

                  } 



                var PlannedSprint = data[i].PlannedSprint;


                var Element = data[i].Element;

                document.getElementById("div"+Column+"_"+Team).innerHTML = "";
                $("#div"+Column+"_"+Team).append(Element);

            }
```

Can someone explain why

```
document.getElementById("div"+Column+"_"+Team).innerHTML = "";
```

is interrupting the loop, it works for the first columns but then it just stops. When i remove that piece of the code it works perfectly and loop through all the columns.

Comment: check your browser console for errors

Comment: `gEBI()` doesn't interrupt your code, but trying to set `innerHTML` of `null` breaks the loop.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Just checked the console, it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: @Solen Now you know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The "div"+Column+"_"+Team element is probably not created in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

I would inspect the HTML and ensure that the div you are expecting exists. Checking document.getElementById("div"+Column+"_"+Team) before setting it's HTML will help avoid the issue.